# How to copy to a smaller container

Tags: c++, containers

If I want to do a copy, but the target container is smaller than the source one. Is there a simple way to do it? What I could think is to copy the target size elements and for the remaining elements, copy to target.back_inserter(). That is, call copy() twice. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: You're going to need to give a concrete example, stating your requirements explicitly.

Comment: resize for second container.Then copy elements.

Comment: How about the obvious `container1 = container2;`?